# Wrapping entire method in try/catch vs specific lines?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting an exception a large method. It's a null reference error. I'm going to add some additional exception handling and logging to this method.

Will I get better exception details if I wrap the entire inner method code in one large try/catch? Or will it produce the same outcome?

The current exception points to the closing brace of this large method.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's one large try catch or many smaller try catches, you will still see the same null reference exception.  You should be checking your variables to make sure they're not null before trying to access them.

Comment: Show us the code snippet of what you're trying to do; that way there's no possibility that we'll give you bad advice because of something you didn't mention.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the same exception in the same code, the range of the try-catch won't make a difference. The callstack will point you to the method the error happened in and the code line.

You could break your long methods into smaller ones (which is good for a bunch of reasons) to get a better callstack.

Comment: The call stack doesn't point to the line that failed. It points to the ending brace of the method. Braces don't execute anything.

Comment: @4thSpace are you sure you recompiled it? Maybe the debug information is stale. Are you running the program directly from VS or are you attaching?

Comment: It is logging the exception. I'm not attached and can't because of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

`try...catch` should only enclose the code you expect to throw the exception you're going to catch. The more code you include in the `try` the greater chance that exceptions that should *not* be caught, will be.

However, `NullReferenceException`, is not something you'd typically try to catch. You shouldn't *expect* your code to fail in this way. Rather, you ward against it in the first place by doing proper null-checking.